# Token balance of all addresses in contract

Tags: erc-20

How can I retrieve the token balance of all the addresses used to store a spesific ERC20 token in Solidity?

That is, without having a list of addresses, but only relying on the data in the smart contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible to answer without knowing the code for the token you're interested in, but typically an ERC20 token stores balances in a `mapping`, which cannot be enumerated. That means there's no way from just the data in the smart contract to get a list of token holders.

Tools that do this sort of thing discover the addresses by observing events triggered by the contract instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This would be from a contract that I developed myself, hence I would have all possibilites to make the proper function to do this. Is it still not possible to do directly?

Comment: Then you can just keep an array.